# /usr/bin/ld: Dwarf Error

Tags: g++, ld, nvcc, dwarf

I'm trying to compile a complex application with nvcc, and a need to change the compiler from mpic++ to g++, since that I'm having this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '3', this reader only handles version 2 information.
```

What is Dwarf? What this error means?

Any tip to solve it? What usefull informations I'm missing here?

Comment: For information about what DWARF is, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If cleaning up the mpic++ object files doesn't solve it you can tell g++ not to emit DWARF3 info with `-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf`

Comment: Apparently, there was some files that should have been cleaned and were not include in the Makefile... so I was trying to object files from mpic++ and g++.

Thanks